# Why does my wordpress admin not work locally

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved my Wordpress website from its live location to my local server and made sure the URL's were properly changed in the database.

The site runs smoothly and I can navigate through all the pages just fine, but when I try to access the admin page, the screen is completely blank. I can get to the login page and it reads my credentials but when it tries to log me in, nothing appears.

Is there something I'm missing?

I am using MAMP, running on Apache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be some kind of PHP error occurring; check your logs or create a blank file in your site's root called `PHP_errors.log` and add the following to your `.htaccess` file

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /path/to/your/site/PHP_errors.log
```

then refresh the page causing the problem and check if that log now has something in it. There might still be a URL that's pointing to the live server instead of your local one.

Comment: This is of course presuming that you're using Apache as your web server. If you're using IIS or other, please update your question since this is critical information we'd need in order to help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and isn't showing me any errors. When I log in to wp-login.php the wp-admin loads as if there is a page but it is a blank screen.

Comment: @TommyCoffee -- ok, the next thing you can try is to just get it to work is to remove any other themes you might be using or if that doesn't solve the issue, to remove any plugins you've enabled. Something somewhere could be introducing "white space" which is usually the root of all white screens.

Comment: Well removing my theme and plugins would remove my need to have it local. I'll try it though.

Comment: Yup, apparently it is the plugin, "WP e-Commerce" that is causing this. How frustrating, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @TommyCoffee -- white space are line breaks or spaces before or after any PHP delimiters (`<?php`, `<?` or `?>`) in your scripts. Most IDEs and text editors should have a setting which tells it to strip these from your files when saving them.

Comment: do you have any recommendations on how I can find this whitespace to get the plugin working correct?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10353/discussion-between-stealthyninja-and-tommy-coffee)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a PHP error from your Wordpress files you can go to your wp-config and turn on debug mode. This will then display all the PHP errors for you.

Search for

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Comment out this line a replace it with.

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);